# Windows: findstr - how to print 3 lines before and after matched lines?

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

In Windows 7, If I want to find some text in a file, I use the following command.

```
findstr "find_this" trace.log
```

this prints all lines that contains text "find_this". OK.
But I need to print also 3 lines before and 3 line after mached lines.
How I can do this by command **findstr**?

On Unix I can do this by "grep"

```
 grep -B 3 -A 3 find_this trace.log
```

But how I can do this on Windows?

Answer (score 35):

If you are open for a command in Powershell (since you seem to on Win7), ..

```
PS C:\Users\user> Get-Content data.txt
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
eleven
twelve

PS C:\Users\user> Get-Content data.txt | Select-String -Pattern four -Context 2,4

  two
  three
> four
  five
  six
  seven
  eight
```

The Get-Content command gets the the file specified. The Select-String command takes a pattern that you want to find. The Context command let's you specify how many lines (before/after) that you want to be shown (around the line that it matched).

Comment: Or like this (on powershell) :  
Select-String -Path "trace.log" -Pattern "find_this" -Context 3, 3

Comment: My real-worl usage to scan for robocopy log errors within a .CMD: c:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "(Select-String -Path $env:LOG -Pattern ' \(0x0000....\) ' -Context 0,1 | Out-String).Trim()"

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in the windows command line:

```
powershell Select-String -Path "trace.log" -Pattern "find_this" -Context 3,3
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72DMk.png)

'Context 3,3' means to display 3 lines above and 3 lines below

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` on Windows in a number of ways, ordered by ascending overkill-ness:

- Grep for Windows: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm
- Cygwin's package "grep": https://cygwin.com/
- WSL: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux

Comment: i have encounter situations where using solutions like this kinda break the command in mixes with pipes and other commands, so the answer about switching to powershell should be the answer.

Comment: Never happened to me with Cygwin's shell and its commands. Windows cmd pipes are not so reliable though

Comment: just to add context: 
awslogs python cmd, imported with windows pip, then using gitbash to run it pipe grep on it breaks it.

Comment: None of the solutions I proposed is like that, and they work fine. Just posted it because the OP uses grep so with this you can use the same grep switches that you already know from Unix